# Cloud9 keyboard shortcut for going to workspace tree

Tags: cloud9-ide

In the Cloud9 IDE I would like to be able to go to the workspace tree by means of a keyboard shortcut. However, I can't find the key binding to do so. I've looked at the Cloud9 key binding editor and on various places on the web. 
Could somebody perhaps tell me what the shortcut I'm looking for is?

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1):

You can't get to the workspace tree directly, but there are two ways to get there:

- Viewing the current file in the file tree:

Ctrl-Shift-L or Cmd-Shift-L

- Finding a file within the tree

Ctrl-E or Cmd-E

Comment: Thanks, your suggestions work fine. shift-esc shortcut works as well, as is suggested in the comment below.

Answer (score 1):

In commands panel type focus, the first suggestion should be `focusTree` with `shift-esc` shortcut on windows

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the fastest way to get to the workspace tree.